# Autoresize UITextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITextField inside of a UITableViewCell to create a form.
I would like to the UITextField automatically resizes with the UITableViewCell (on iPhone and iPad, portrait and landscape). But its width is only 9.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.accessoryView = field;
    [field sizeToFit];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrong interpreted `-sizeToFit` method. This method cause that `UITextField` changes your frame to contains all text inside. I mean, after you call this method, you text field will be the same size as text inside (textfied without scrolls).

Try to use `-setAutoresizingMask` on `UITextField` and set `UI...FlexibleWidth` and `UI...FlexibleHeight` and set `[field setFrame:cell.bounds]`.

And please read apple documentation and other topic on stackoverflow about how to create cells from Nib. It's very useful.

Comment: you have to call `[field setFrame:cell.bounds]` and `UITextField` should be fit to cell. Try to call this in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. I'm not sure but your cell will be size (0,0) with your code above. Please read this: http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Use property like setFrame and give value like cell.bounds.
as below

```
[txtFiled setFrame : cell.bounds];
```